# Isn't this Exception example wrong?

Tags: java, exception

So I'm just learning exceptions in Java, I'm looking at an example, but it's either wrong or I still don't understand it.

Here's the code:

```
command1;
try {
    command2;
    command3;
    try {
        command4;
        command5;
    } catch (MyException e) { command6; }
    command7;
} catch (IOException e) {
    command8;
} catch (OwnException e) {
    command9;
} finally {
    command10;
}
command11;
```

And then it's written down which commands will run in different scenarios, but command7 is almost never run, only in one scenario, if a MyException occurs during command4.

Isn't that wrong? I'm just learning so there's a chance I'm wrong here, but there's also a chance the teacher's notes are wrong, wouldn't this only be true if the } after command6 was after command7? So command6 and command7 should be in one catch block to explain why command7 is never executed, only in this one case (and I guess it'd also execute if a MyException occured during command5, but not every scenario is played out in the notes).

---

Comment: you're right and your teacher is wrong.  But the best way to settle this is by running it yourself. It would have been quicker than writing up an SO question :)

Comment: as @sstan said, use an ide (or ideone.com) and play with the thing, you can then see it with your own eyes ;)

Comment: " but command7 is almost never run, only in one scenario, if a MyException occurs during command4" . That is not entirely true. Command 7 also runs if there are not exception encountered during command4 and command5. not being command7 within catch block after command6 has a purpose.

Comment: @Jimmy I've just checked again, according to my teacher's notes if there are no exceptions at all then command1,2,3,4,5,10 and 11 runs, but if there's no typo and command7 is not in a catch block on purpose then it should also run, shouldn't it?

Comment: A consistent indentation and brace placement would have helped see things more clearly.

Comment: yep, command 7 should run if there are not exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command7;` should run every time unless `command2;`, `command3;` or potentially `command6;` cause an `IOException` or an `OwnException`. Obviously `command7;` will not run if the program crashes from anything unhanded but other than that there shouldn't be a way around it. If `command11;` runs and neither `command8;` or `command9;` ran then `command7;` should have ran. If you moved the bracket as you stated, then `command5;` could also trigger the `MyException` that would run 6 and 7.